# Skip/Ignore Javascript error and continue with next statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

There are lots of pages in my project (Asp.net mvc), I have set a timer with js in layout page, I am using this timer to alert after every specific(15 min) time, But when I got js error in any page, My time stops and code not execute.

I need, if any error comes in any page, my code should be execute after its mentioned timer.

I got a solution with try, catch. But there are more than 30 page in my site with javascript and it is difficult to put try catch in every page.

I need something global for this.

Answer (score 0):

To suppress all JavaScript error messages on your HTML page, you can put the following script code in the **HEAD** section of your page:

```
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
<!--
function silentErrorHandler() {return true;}
window.onerror=silentErrorHandler;
//-->
</SCRIPT>
```